# Error: require() of ES Module in React-gauge-chart, NextJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, charts

it shows this error

> when you try to render the package component:
>  require() of ES
> Module /node_modules/d3/src/index.js from
> /node_modules/react-gauge-chart/dist/GaugeChart/index.js not
> supported. Instead change the require of /node_modules/d3/src/index.js
> in /node_modules/react-gauge-chart/dist/GaugeChart/index.js to a
> dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import using next dynamic

```js
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const GaugeChart = dynamic(() => import('react-gauge-chart'), { ssr: false });
```